# What is a Dynamic View in LokiJS?

Tags: javascript, lokijs

I am working on a Hybrid App where I am storing data with LokiJS.

I read the documentation at 
[LokiJS Website](http://lokijs.org), and some of it on [Rawgit](https://rawgit.com/techfort/LokiJS/master/jsdoc/index.html), and i am good at basic concepts like creation of db, collection and operations on them.

But I really did not understand what a Dynamic View is! :|

And also, how do we write code asynchronously with LokiJS? I am confused with the Adapters concept too!

Can someone help me on this in simple words or some clear reference where explanation for this exist?!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to the LokiJS documentation at http://techfort.github.io/LokiJS/DynamicView.html

DynamicView class is a versatile 'live' view class which can have filters and sorts applied. Collection.addDynamicView(name) instantiates this DynamicView object and notifies it whenever documents are add/updated/removed so it can remain up-to-date.